# As expected or as expectation

Tags: grammar, as

I think that "as expected" sounds less weird than "as expectation", but "as" is a preposition, so there should be a noun after it. Which is correct, as expected or as expectation?

Which is correct?

- The planet should be observed on July 12 as expected.
- The planet should be observed on July 12 as expectation.

Comment: I think it's an *adverb* and not preposition. *As expectation* is possible but in different context: *As expectation weighed heavily on Nigeria at the tournament, they could not go beyond the group stage...*

Comment: There isn't enough context, which is why I've deleted my answer. It could be either, so please add the sentence this appears in, and preferably the one before and after it as well.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: @KVD The part "which is correct, *as expected* or *as expectation*" is easy to answer. Unfortunately, the point you raised, *"as" is a preposition, so there should be a noun after it*, is quite difficult to answer, because it makes the answerer have to clarify what *as* functions as in *as expected* first. Is this *as* really a preposition? Is it an adverb? Is it a conjunction? It's difficult to pinpoint (at least for me, on feet). For example, consider this: "He walked across." What does this *across* function as? An adverb or a preposition? How about this: "He walked across the bridge."?

Comment: I believe that when you said *"as" is a preposition, so there should be a noun after it.*, you thought of something like "He worked *as* a designer." which doesn't apply to this case of *as expected*. In short, *as* doesn't always work as a preposition.

Comment: You can rephrase the sentence so that it receives a noun, but it comes out more awkward: "As scientists have expected, the planet will be visible on July 12." I believe the noun is implied. As a lone sentence it makes little sense, but within the context of a passage it should come directly after a sentence which clarifies the implied subject: "Scientists have predicted a close trajectory of the planet Mars to Earth. [...] The planet should be observed on July 12 as expected."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, **never** take some grammar rule you found somewhere, or that someone told you, and try to apply it indiscriminately to every sentence that you find. In this case, the grammar rule is not that "*as* is a preposition, therefore it takes a noun", but "**if** *as* is used as a preposition, it usually takes a noun".

I agree with the comments that *as* should not be seen as a preposition in this sentence.

Having a quick look at what the OALD has to say about this, when we look up [as (preposition)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/as_1) we find:

> **1** used to describe somebody/something appearing to be somebody/something else
>   *They were all dressed as clowns.*
>   *The bomb was disguised as a package.*
>   **2** used to describe the fact that somebody/something has a particular job or function
>   *She works as a courier.*
>   *Treat me as a friend.*

None of these sentences seems to follow the pattern of your *as expected* example.

Now, when we look at [as (adverb)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/as_2) we find this:

> **1** as… as… used when you are comparing two people or things, or two situations
>   **2** used to say that something happens in the same way
>   *As always, he said little.*
>   *The ‘h’ in honest is silent, as in ‘hour’.*

Now, in the sentence *as always, he said little*, I see the structure of your sentence; I can replace *always* with *expected*:

> As *always*, he said little.
>   As *expected*, he said little.
>   As *every morning*, he said little.

Answer (score 1):

We only say, "as expected."

a mannered way of saying it might be,

"As *per* expectation."

Answer (score 0):

Correct examples:

> - **As expected**, the project went well.
> - **As per my expectation**, she completed the task on time.
> - Things went **as expected**.
> - Things went **as per my expectation(s)**.
> - **As a high/large/unreasonable expectation** had been placed on the outcome, Sarah was disappointed.
> - Things did not go **as Sarah had expected**.

Answer (score 0):

The correct form is "as expected" (in a way that was planned or thought likely to happen). To find the answer to your question, I guess it would be better not to look at it as a "preposition-noun" issue, as you mentioned. Consider it as the short form of "as is/was expected".  It might help understand what's going on.  Example:

As expected, the whole family was shocked by the news.

Comment: I don't think in your examples, _As expected_ is an ellipsed form of _As it is expected_. I can imagine it being _as would be expected_, but it's easier just to see _as_ as an adverb.

Comment: Why not  "as it was expected, the whole family..."?

Comment: _As it was expected_, unless _it_ refers to a known piece of news, is ungrammatical (at least, to me - I don't think I have or would ever say that).

Comment: What's your take on this? "As expected, the party was a great success."

Comment: You mean "as it is/was expected" is not grammatically acceptable?

Comment: The sentence is still grammatical, but including what you've said is ellipsed isn't grammatical. _As was expected_ is grammatical, though.

Comment: Could you rephrase this sentence, please? "As expected, the party was a great success."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14829/discussion-between-jimsug-and-m-n).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the very useful comment of Damkerng has the answer in it.

If you place *[expectation](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/expectation)* (a noun) after *as*, the *as* becomes *[preposition (line #3)](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/as)*. This is what you stated in your question.

What the structure of *as...[noun]* conveys very first thing to us is... *to be..*

> He acted **as a clown**

And certainly, this is not the case here.

So, to answer *Which is correct, as expected or as expectation?*... my vote to :

> The planet should be observed on July 12 *as expected.*